# Why do all getX() calls in Selenium take so long?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to do some web scraping in Selenium. It seems like even after I've put all the WebElements on the site into an ArrayList, it takes the program a significant fraction of a second to complete each call to **`getText()`**, **`getAttribute()`**, or **`getTagName()`**.

The page I'm scraping uses Javascript.

Is this because each call involves re-downloading material from the web page?

I had assumed that Selenium would download the web page up front, store the elements in fast memory on my computer, and then iterate through that material when I use **`getText()`** or **`getAttribute()`**. Is that wrong? If so, is there a way to download the whole page, extract the elements and put them in my computer's memory, and then process them that way? Here's some example code:

```
            List<WebElement> all_elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("*"));
            for (int i = 0; i < all_elements.size() - 2; i++) {
                //If the tag name two elements ahead is "em", then the current
                //element is the title of the paper, and the "em" element is the author.
                //Search up to 10 elements for a "Full Text" link.
                if (all_elements.get(i + 2).getTagName().equalsIgnoreCase("em")) {
                    String title = all_elements.get(i).getText();
                    String author = all_elements.get(i + 2).getText();
                    String full_text = "";
                    for (int j = 3; j < 10 && full_text.isEmpty(); j++) {
                        if (all_elements.get(i + j).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("full text"))
                            full_text = all_elements.get(i + j).getAttribute("href");
                    }
                    System.out.println("Title: " + title);
                    System.out.println("Author: " + author);
                    System.out.println("Full text link: " + full_text);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this myself. The problem is that Selenium does a "freshness check" every time you call any of these functions on an element. My solution was to extract the source from the WebDriver after the page loaded, then insert it into a Jsoup Document via the Jsoup.parse() function. I was then able to extract the elements without any "freshness" checks, which dramatically sped up the program.